# An exception of type 'System.invalidOperationException' occures in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I'm here following a tutorial step by step and can't get rid of this exception. My connection string looks fine. It doesn't happen in the tutorial so I have no idea what is wrong.
 It brings me to this line Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ATSTest.Models;


namespace ATSTest.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);

            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ATSTest.Models
{   
    [Table("Employees")]
    public class Employee
    {

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string HiredDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Connection String

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AssetTracking;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

EmployeeContext Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ATSTest.Models

    {
        public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if the database table Employees was created ?

Comment: Yes I have a table called Employees in my Sql Server and I copied the exact connection string into Web.config correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: are you using this connection string correctly in the EmployeeContext class ?  The code of that class is not here.

Comment: As far as I can tell. I edited my post to show the EmployeeContext class. Please let me know if you see anything wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is you are not using the connection string.

You will have to pass connection string name as shown in below example.

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeContext()
        : base("EmployeeContext")
    {

    }

    // DbSet's here
    publlic DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It now gives me this error. System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements and brings me back to the same line it did before. Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);

Comment: Thats because you dont have any data in Employees.  Use SingleOrDefault method instead of Single.  This would return null instead of throwing exception.

Comment: Please refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for knowing how to seed data for testing purpose.

Comment: I do have data in my Employees table. Thanks though I guess I'll check out that Microsoft tutorial.

Comment: If you have data then where clause id may not be matching with any data in the table.  Please use the ID for which data is existing.  Also if it has solved your issue, would suggest to mark it as answer... ;)

Comment: Singleordefault stops the error instead it just shows Details in the title instead of any of my data. I guess that fixed It and for some reason my database data isn't working I'm not sure.